Server Actions not executing concurrently in next js
I read an article about server actions, and I'm experiencing a related issue.

Server Actions are designed for mutations that update server-side state; they are not recommended for data fetching. Accordingly, frameworks implementing Server Actions typically process one action at a time and do not have a way to cache the return value.


I want to confirm if we will be running multiple server actions concurrently in Next js?
I am using next js 14.0.3 version.
https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server
